# Design to convert existing application to micro services?

Tags: java, web-applications, microservices

I already have multi module application where high level maven modules depends on low level modules. Below are the some of the modules :-

```
Search
user-creation
utils-common
notice-email
.......
```

Search has the business logic related common to search module
user-creation has the business logic related to user module
utils-common  contains helper methods
notice-email  has the business logic related to email

All the modules use common single DB.

Now to convert any module(say email) to micro service, here is mine understanding :-

1. Email will be separate war application
2. It can continue to same common DB
3. It will have its own authentication mechanism where other modules will send username/pwd and email services can verify through same DB
4. Earlier transaction boundaries  were spanning across modules. Now email module will have its own transaction boundary . My question here is what
   if i needs transaction across modules/microservices ? For example:- In single transaction, First User is created but while sending email(thru email micro serv),
   error occurs, Is it possible to roll back complete transaction ?

Comment: Whenever I need a transaction across services, I implement a compensatory logic (I believe this is the 'official term') inside services. 

One thing one may want to wonder is why those services use the same DB (I assume this means the same schema, the same set of tables). Which in general I perceive as not a good idea, since you have multiple components that can change the same data...